# How to make regex matching fail if checked string still has leftover characters?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check a string with a regular expression, and this check should only pass if the string contains only *h, *d, *w and/or *m where * can be any number.

So far I've got this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]h)|([0-9]d)|([0-9]w)|([0-9]m)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(strToCheck);
        if(m.find()){     
            //matching succesful code
        }
```

And it works to detect if there are any of the number-letter combinations present in the checked string, but it also works if the input is, for instance, "12x5d", because it has "5d" in it. I don't know if this is a code problem or a regex problem. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

EDIT:
Thank you for your answers so far, but as requested, I'll try to clarify a bit. A string like "1w 2d 3h" or "1w 1w" is valid and should pass, but something like "1w X 2d 3h", "1wX 2d" or "w d h" should fail.

Comment: Please edit your question to add some examples of strings that should match, and strings that should not (or show what you want extracted from some strings that contain "leftover" characters) (e.g.: `12x5d 4h 9whello` should give the results `5d`, `4h`, and `9w`) or something similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `m.matches()` or add `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the regex resp.

edit but if you wan sequences of these delimited by whitespace (as mentioned in the comments) you can use

```
Pattern.compile("\\b\\d[hdwm]\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(strToCheck);
while(m.find()){
    //matching succesful code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think you should use [`matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) instead of `find()`. The former matches the entire string against the regex, whereas the latter searches within the string.

Secondly, you can simplify the regex like so: `"[0-9][hdwm]"`.

Finally, if the number can contain multiple digits, use the `+` operator: `"[0-9]+[hdwm]"`

Comment: I also need it to match if the string contains "1d 2h 3w" for example, this (and by extension, the other answers) only seems to work for one combination at a time

Comment: @Slyder: In such a case, you could use `"\\b[0-9][hdwm]\\b"` with `find()`. The `\b` matches a word boundary. The first call to `find()` will give `"1d"`, the second `"2h"` and the third `"3w"`.

Comment: @slyder please add that info to the question

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9][hdwm]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(strToCheck);
        if(m.matches()){     
            //matching succesful code
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only accept things like `5d` as a complete word, rather than just part of one, you can use the `\b` "word border" markers in regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b([0-9]h)|([0-9]d)|([0-9]w)|([0-9]m)\\b");
```

This will let you match a string like `"Dimension: 5h"` while rejecting a string like `"Dimension: 12wx5h"`.

(If, on the other hand, you only want to match if the entire string is just `5d` or the like, then use `matches()` as others have suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this `"^\\d+[hdwm]$"`. Which should only match on the desired strings.